# How to find distance between 2 vectors where some fields are strings(Name, Address etc) and others are number

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, knn

I have to find distance between 2 records. Each records is a vector of multiple fields. Some of these fields are Numeric. Others are strings. How can I come up with a single value for distance.

I can individually calculate String Distance for each string variable and Euclidean distance for the numeric ones. In that case, how do I combine both these distance values

Answer (score 3):

That really depends on what you're trying to do. For example instead of finding distance between strings that are addresses it might be worth taking the time to convert them into geo-locations and measure their distance.

Finding distance between strings of names doesn't really make sense but you can find their string distance and use some weights so they don't make numerical values ineffective.

Essentially you will need some type of feature extraction of pre-processing for your text data.